# T-SQL inner join first result of inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, Property and PropertyImage. 1 Property has multiple images

I need to get all the properties and just 1 PropertyImage per Property.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

```
Property: PropertyID, Name
PropertyImage: PropertyImageID, PropertyID, Source, Type
```

Thanks

Comment: Which `PropertyImage` result do you need? Just an arbitrary one or a specific one?

Comment: Which property image do you want?  can you give the table structure of propertyimage?

Comment: first one is fine - any basically

Comment: If a property has multiple images, does it matter which one you pick? Is there an order of presence?

Comment: Which PropertyImage do you want?  The top 1 of what?  Or does it even matter?  What field(s) do you need from PropertyImage?

Comment: @user441365 - There is no `First` one unless you specify ordered by what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example where all the records from Property is selected and the last record from PropertyImage, assuming that the id column is an identity column and the last record is the one you need.  You will need to adjust based on your exact column names and requirements.

```
SELECT p.PropertyID, p.Name, pi.PropertyImageID, pi.Source, pi.Type 
  FROM Property p 
       INNER JOIN PropertyImage pi
         ON pi.PropertyImageId = (SELECT MAX(sub.PropertyImageId) 
                                    FROM PropertyImage sub
                                   WHERE sub.PropertyId = p.PropertyId)
```

EDIT: Added column names in select

Comment: that doesn't work - it thorws an error here: WHERE sub.PropertyId = p.PropertyId

Comment: I am not sure why not - I use many variations of the same select on a daily basis.  Did you get an error or no results?

Comment: Do you have the WHERE in the right place?  The 'WHERE' is part of the sub-query '(SELECT MAX(sub.PropertyImageId) FROM PropertyImage sub WHERE sub.PropertyId = p.PropertyId)'

Comment: @user441365 It's valid SQL, and it works for me. I even created some empty tables and ran that exact query -- it works. You must have copied it wrong.

Comment: Can you show me the SQL that does not work?  The syntax above is correct

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH PI
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyID 
                                       ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
         FROM   PropertyImage)
SELECT P.PropertyID,
       P.Name,
       PI.PropertyImageID,
       PI.Source,
       PI.Type
FROM   Property P
       JOIN PI
         ON P.PropertyID = PI.PropertyID
WHERE  PI.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to

```
SELECT P.PropertyID, P.Name, max(PI.PropertyImageID) 
from Property P 
INNER JOIN PropertyImage PI 
ON P.PropertyID = PI.PropertyID
GROUP BY P.PropertyID, P.name
```

Example data and desired output would help to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I need to get Source and Type from PropertyImage

Comment: See Leons post; Its got what your after.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
Select Property.PropertyID
FROM Property
INNER JOIN PropertyImage pi on pi.PropertyID = Property.PropertyID 
WHERE pi.PropertyImageID = (SELECT MAX(PropertyImageID) FROM PropertyImage WHERE PropertyID = Property.PropertyID)
```

That should only get the PropertyImage with the highest 'PropertyImageID' value. You could change the `MAX(PropertyImageID)` logic depending on your needs.